# add a string suffx to each value in a string column using Pandas if it doesn't contain a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add "raw" to the end of each value in a string column if it doesn't contain the word raw.

```
from pandas import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("files/Template_DataCatalogue_Test.csv", sep=";")
df.drop(df.index[3:], inplace=True)
df = df[~df["Title"].str.contains("raw"), "raw " + df["Title"].astype(str)]
print(df)
```

Comment: Could you show a sample of the dataframe? And the expected output

Comment: The comment below worked for me :-)

Comment: Thanks for that! I have accepted it now :-)

Comment: Not sure what you mean? @jezrael

Comment: Oh, little busy now @jezrael thanks for pointing out a reference though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[~df["Title"].str.contains("raw"), 'Title'] = "raw " + df["Title"].astype(str)
```

For end:

```
df.loc[~df["Title"].str.contains("raw"), 'Title'] = df["Title"].astype(str) + " raw"
```

Comment: Thanks for that! If I want to check if two columns rows have value raw, do you know how I can do that? ##df.loc[~df(df["Title"] & df["DLZ"]).str.contains("raw"), 'Title'] = df["Title"].astype(str) + " raw"

Comment: @Toni - simpliest is use `df.loc[~(df["Title"] + ' '  + df["DLZ"]).str.contains("raw"), 'Title'] = df["Title"].astype(str) + " raw"`